# Manga with an expelled heir with no skills who gains a skill from the worm children of a bee monster

Tags: story-identification, manga, litrpg

I once read a manga about a guy who I think was the heir to some Japanese sort of a clan on an island. He was expelled by his father for not being able to get any skills, so he came to the mainland and joined an adventurer guild (where of course he was teased for being weak), joins a party.

He is betrayed by them when faced by a bee-type strong monster. The bee takes him to feed its million worm-like children in a cave. At near death he starts eating them and gets a skill. Then he uses the skill to regenerate and devour all of the worms (the worms are monster hatchlings).

The manga has about 4 to 7 chapters and was probably a light novel too.

Comment: Is this a "reincarnation" isekai or a "portal" isekai? Or is this general fantasy LitRPG where people are aware of their stats?

Comment: General fantasy LitRPG, yes they are aware of their stats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like *The Revenge of The Soul Eater*

> The Mitsurugi household was given the important task of guarding the
> demon gate by the emperor.
>
> Sora Mitsurugi, who was the heir of the family, was called on to take
> the trial ceremony at the age of thirteen.
>
> The trial is something that he must overcome in order to learn the
> phantom blade style that was passed down the Mitsurugi household from
> generation to generation.
>
> The other seven pupils of the same age who had taken the trial have
> all passed. And now only Sora remained.
>
> His father, brother, fiancee, and a pair of siblings who have watched
> over him were all looking, as Sora’s trial ceremony solemnly began…

This is the synopsis on [NovelUpdates](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/the-revenge-of-the-soul-eater/).

The part you describe where he is betrayed happens on the end of manga chapter 1.3, and the beginning of chapter 2.

He is out on the woods exploring alone, when he finds his old party. After they go on their ways, the party encounters the giant bee, named The Lord of the Flies. While trying to escape, the party mage shoots him, so they can escape using him as bait.

After he is captured by The Lord of the Flies, he eats its baby maggots, and acquires some sort of dark scythe.

Comment: thanks a lot, that was the one i was looking for.